# Phonegap - jQuery Mobile and very large listview

Tags: json, listview, jquery-mobile, cordova

in a page of my app, developed with Phonegap and jQuery Mobile, I loading a data from json external file. These data compose my listview on my web application.

The problem is that when I click a voice from the list, the page called is  flickering; the same effect when I go back to the list page (header particulary).

I think that the longer lists should be paginate. Which is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="d" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" >

<div data-role="footer" data-theme="d" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" >
```

Fixed the data-position="fixed" and data-tap-toggle="false", when you tap on page, header and footer will not be flickered .